# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "cmsg_nxthdr" referenced by "libpcap.so"

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, dlopen

I am new to NDK. I am trying to create an app that can capture packets. I have compiled libpcap from https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap

Now when I try to run the application on an android tablet, it gives the following error

```
07-24 02:29:50.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2014): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-24 02:29:50.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2014): Process: com.example.lpcap, PID: 2014
07-24 02:29:50.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2014): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "cmsg_nxthdr" referenced by "libpcap.so"...
07-24 02:29:50.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2014):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:364)
07-24 02:29:50.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2014):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
07-24 02:29:50.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2014):     at com.example.lpcap.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:37)
07-24 02:29:50.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2014):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-24 02:29:50.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2014):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
07-24 02:29:50.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2014):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
07-24 02:29:50.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2014):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
07-24 02:29:50.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2014):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
07-24 02:29:50.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2014):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-24 02:29:50.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2014):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-24 02:29:50.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2014):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-24 02:29:50.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2014):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-24 02:29:50.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2014):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-24 02:29:50.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2014):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-24 02:29:50.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2014):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-24 02:29:50.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2014):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-24 02:29:50.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2014):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-24 02:29:50.627: E/AndroidRuntime(2014):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

socket.h in ndk has this symbol. I am not sure if it is getting compiled. I have to manually add it, how should I go about it? Following is the Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

libpcap_PSRC =  pcap-linux.c pcap-usb-linux.c  pcap-can-linux.c pcap-netfilter-linux.c  
libpcap_FSRC =  fad-gifc.c
libpcap_CSRC =  pcap.c inet.c gencode.c optimize.c nametoaddr.c etherent.c \
    savefile.c sf-pcap.c sf-pcap-ng.c pcap-common.c \
    bpf_image.c bpf_dump.c
libpcap_GENSRC = scanner.c grammar.c bpf/net/bpf_filter.c version.c lpcap.c

libpcap_SRC =   $(libpcap_PSRC) $(libpcap_FSRC) $(libpcap_CSRC) $(libpcap_GENSRC)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:=\
    $(libpcap_SRC)
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES :=  libc cutils
LOCAL_CFLAGS:=-O2 -g
LOCAL_CFLAGS+= -DSYS_ANDROID=1 -Dyylval=pcap_lval -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -D_U_="__attribute__((unused))" -Dlinux -D__GLIBC__
#-D_GNU_SOURCE
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -ldl -lc 
LOCAL_MODULE:= libpcap
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I am loading this in the java file using

```
static{  
        System.loadLibrary("pcap");  
    }
```

I haven't called any method. I just want it to be able to load the library without problems. Please help me solve this.

Comment: This is unlikely to work anyway, as you will find it very difficult to run the application process into which a jni library is linked with sufficient unix-level permission on most Android platforms.  Most people would capture packets from a native helper executable that is either setuid or run via a hacked 'su' root shim; but even then you will likely only see those originating with or intended for the device itself.  Much easier to put it on a dedicated wifi network and intercept the traffic there.

Answer (score 0):

Move your precompiled libpcap to the JNI folder. If you are targetting multiple architectures you need to create multiple folders within your JNI corresponding to each architecture(armeabi,x86 etc) and place the .so files accordingly. Modify your manifest file like below to include your prebuilt shared library

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libpcap
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libpcap.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := projectname
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := projectname.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

projectname corresponds to the module of libpcap and projectname.cpp corresponds to the actual source file